# Java Problem: creating a string from a sequence of bytes

Tags: java, string

I came across the following program and its showing unexpected results.

```
public class StringFromByte
{
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
             byte bytes[] = new byte[256];

             for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                 bytes[i] = (byte)i;

             String str = new String(bytes);
             for(int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; i++)
                 System.out.print((int)str.charAt(i) + " ");
       }
}
```

Technically this program should print the integers from 0 to 255 in order. But if you ran the program sometimes it shows this sequence (0 to 255) sometimes it shows some other sequence. Its behavior is unspecified. What's going on?

Comment: I can't explain the non-deterministic behavior, but I do see one issue. If you cast int values over 127 to a byte, it's actually a negative value which when cast back to an int remains negative, so even if this was deterministic, you wouldn't get back 0 -> 255 printed out. This doesn't even address the encoding issued involved with throwing random bytes into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String constructor you're using uses a default character encoding. It could interpret some bytes as multi-byte characters.

Try this:

```
         String str = new String(bytes, CharSet.forName( "ISO-8859-1" ));
```

See also the [CharSet API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), which lists standard CharSet names.

Disclaimer: I usually use this constructor for UTF-8.

Comment: but how does the encoding change at run-time? As Umesh mentioned that "sometimes" the order changes. Should n't the encoding effect remain same across runs?

Comment: @peakit, it wasn't clear whether all the runs where on the same platform with the same options.

Answer (score 1):

Its behaviour is not unspecified.

A character is not the same thing as a byte, but the person who wrote this doesn't know that.  There are about six million characters in unicode, but there are only 256 unique bytes.  This means that many of the unicode characters are represented by more than one byte.

Some of the bytes in your example indicate that the character needs more than one byte, but I'm guessing that the "next" bytes in the array don't correspond to valid UTF-8 characters.

To properly encode a String from a set of bytes that are not UTF-8, [use this constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29).
You will have to provide the correct character set so Java can then understand how the bytes fit into characters.

The reason you're getting different results is because of the environment.  Each environment has a default Locale which specifies it's preferred character set.  The constructor you are using always assumes a UTF-8 character set, so some of the times it mistranslates the source bytes into gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, the maximum value a Java `byte` type can hold is 127 (the byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer).

Comment: So if you replace those byte casted ints into integers between -127 and 127 would you get the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `byte` with `char` and it works as expected. It's because of byte's maximum 127.